# Possible to query _ListSubscribers and _EnterpriseAttributes and not use All Subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, attribute

I have an E2.0 account with parent/child MIDs and I'm trying to pull in a population for a Journey.

When I combine `_ListSubscribers` with `_EnterpriseAttribute` and declare `ListID = 'All Subs List ID"` the query works fine... when I change the `ListID` value to a specific list value, I get 0 records.

Since the fields are shared across all Lists, I assumed this would work...?

The field we're running the query against is `Joined Mailing List Date`

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
a.[Joined mailing list date], b.SubscriberKey, b.EmailAddress as Email 
FROM ent._EnterpriseAttribute a
JOIN ent._ListSubscribers b  ON a._SubscriberID= b.SubscriberID
WHERE 
b.ListID= '66391' AND 
b.SubscriberKey like 'PRE_%' AND 
b.SubscriberKey Not Like '%@%' AND 
(datediff(d,[Joined mailing list date],getdate()) = 1 OR datediff(d,[Joined mailing list date],getdate()) = 2) AND 
b.SubscriberKey NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberKey FROM Welcome_Suppression)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query data from a specific list that isn't stored in the business unit where you are running the query from. The reason you can access the All Subscribers is because that is shared across all business units.

This is what makes Shared Data Extensions ideal. If you have to use lists, it would likely be easiest to have queries running in each required business unit which will push data into a Data Extension accessible by the business unit running the Journey.

Comment: I think your answer poked me in the right direction... Originally, I was using the ALL SUBS list, but had to change the query at the client's request... but, I kept the ent. prefix on _ListSubscribers (which is no longer necessary).

I'm going to try it without the ent. prefix this afternoon.

Comment: Confirming that removing the ent. prefix from _ListSubscribers fixed the query!

Comment: Glad I could help in a round-about kind of way :P